# Haskell Says My Guard Has A Parse Error

Tags: haskell, whitespace, guard, pattern-guards

So I've been playing with Haskell the past couple of days, and I decided I'd make a basic definition of the Fibonacci sequence. So I wrote this code:

```
main = do
    fib :: (Integral a) => Int -> Int
    fib x
        | x == 0 = 0
        | x == 1 = 1
        | x >= 2 = fib (x - 2) + fib (x - 1)
    do { print (fib 5) }
```

And I get an error message saying:

```
4:17: parse error on input `|'
```

I suspected tab errors, so I tried every whitespace fix I could find, but I just can't find what's wrong!

EDIT: So I did what people suggested, and I have this code now:

```
fib :: (Integral a) => Int -> Int
main = do
    fib x
        | x == 0 = 0
        | x == 1 = 1
        | x >= 2 = fib (x - 2) + fib (x - 1)
    print (fib 5)
```

And I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Any reason why put type signature and function definition into the do block?

Comment: I didn't know what I was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also define `fib` locally to `main` outside of the `do` block. Do bear in mind that `do` is syntactic sugar for the use of various monadic binding functions, and so the syntax accepted within it is not quite the same as that accepted outside it. And, in fact, your `main` doesn't even require the `do` block because you just call `print` rather than chaining any `IO` actions together.

```
main = let
         fib x | x == 0 = 0
               | x == 1 = 1
               | x >= 2 = fib (x - 2) + fib (x + 1)
       in
         print (fib 5)
```

Or you could use `where`:

```
main = print (fib 5)
       where
         fib x | x == 0 = 0
               | x == 1 = 1
               | x >= 2 = fib (x - 2) + fib (x + 1)
```

They're the same, the question is just where the local binding actually goes. `let`..`in` gives you a new block where the new bindings are in scope, while `where` makes its bindings available in the scope of the function it's attached to.

If, as seems eventually likely, you do want a `do` block as well so you can do multiple `IO` actions, you can just put that in place of the call to `print`, like so:

```
main = let
         fib x | x == 0 = 0
               | x == 1 = 1
               | x >= 2 = fib (x - 2) + fib (x + 1)
       in
         do print (fib 5)
            print (fib 6)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should define `fib` outside of `main`, not inside it. And then you should remove at least one of the `do`s from `main`.

Comment: the `do`s aren't a problem I would say, you can nest them. But if you want to bind a variable within a do block you need to use `let`.

Comment: Sure, but they're still bad and weird.

Comment: I moved `fib :: (Integral a) => Int -> Int` to outside "main," but I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to define the function within `do` block without actually using any construct for defining things (like `let`).

Try defining the function outside the block:

```
fib :: (Integral a) => Int -> Int
fib x | x == 0 = 0
      | x == 1 = 1
      | x >= 2 = fib (x - 2) + fib (x - 1)

main = print (fib 5)
```

If you insist on defining the function locally (inside the expression that is formed by statements of the `do` block):

```
main = do
    let
        fib :: (Integral a) => Int -> Int
        fib x | x == 0 = 0
              | x == 1 = 1
              | x >= 2 = fib (x - 2) + fib (x - 1)
    print (fib 5)
```

Notice how `let` is used to bind a new variable `fib` to the function you want.